# Verifying html sort with java

Tags: java, sql, sorting, selenium

I am verifying with Java and Selenium that a column in a table in html is sorted correctly.  The developers use an sql sort.

I get the values in order into a linked list.  I make a copy of the linked list and do a Collections.sort() for ascending (and then reverse it for descending).  I then compare the two lists and be sure they are the same.  I ran into one problem because for `a A b B`, sql sorted as `a A b B`, but Java sorted as `A B a b`.  So someone showed me how to write a sort ignoring case.  This works.

My problem?  Some of the fields contain characters like this: `$@%^!#@`
(no I am not swearing ;-)).  Java sorts these differently from sql.  I put them into an excel spreadsheet and sorted and it sorted as sql did, not as Java did.

Can anyone recommend a sort (I think comparable or comparator) I can use in Java to simulate the sql sort on these characters?  I mean I could painstakingly look at each character and see which it precedes in the SQL sort and write a sort character-by-character but I am hoping there is an easier way.

Thanks

p.s. sql may have been `A a B b`.  I don't remember but that is not important for the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should verify NLS_SORT on your DB session. If its set to 'BINARY', it will match your Java results - A, B, a, b

SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_SORT'; --Value is 'BINARY'
select * from 
(
        select 'B' as x from dual union all
        select 'a' as x from dual union all
        select 'A' as x from dual union all
        select 'b' as x from dual
) a order by x;

For more reference, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#REFRN10127

Comment: Thanks.  I am more concerned with the non-alphanumeric characters like `$!#@` etc.